# "Hussy" for a sewing folder in AE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Does the term "hussy" [alteration of Midde English *husewif* "housewife"] have any currency in modern day AE to refer to a sewing folder, or is it sort of better
known as a derogatory term for a slovenly or sleazy woman?
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hussy

Sources:

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hussy
>
> http://onlinedictionary.datasegment.com/word/hussy
>
> She toiled unremittingly with the aid of a sewing hussy,
> [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=ofhA2miS8YMC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=%22sewing+hussy%22&source=bl&ots=x8lnEe2xkq&sig=CzdywxRdy2HQn97i5zWGy7Qf4g8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=U7YbU9OKAcn8ywP3l4KACA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22sewing%20hussy%22&f=false)>/

Comment: Why do you suspect that it has any currency in that sense? Try to go beyond simply citing dictionaries and explain what you've learned about the words in your research. You may even be able to answer the questions yourself that way.

Comment: Also, try using Google Ngrams for American English. That way you can at least get an idea of written usage.

Comment: @Bradd Szonye I didn't say "currency", but "better known".

Comment: Huh? It says “currency” right there in your question!

Comment: You've now asked several questions that are essentially, “Does [term that Bradd, a native AmE speaker from the Midwest and California, has never even heard of] have any currency in American English?” ... I don't know where you're finding these words, but I can't help but think that there must be **some** better resource to help you, or at least a better approach than posting them all shotgun-style here. Perhaps you should ask on [meta] for advice?

Comment: @BraddSzonye Depends on which of these senses you're referring to.

Comment: You're welcome. It seems to me that you're earnest about figuring out colloquial usage, which can be tricky. I think there must be a better way to get you that information. You might also want to hang out in ELU chat. There are some smart, helpful people there.

Comment: I think some of his questions are really good and some aren't - this being one.  It shows how dated some references are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

Huh?!?

Hussy has *another* connotation?  I'm shocked to find out that it has *anything* to do with sewing.

In AmE it's always used to describe a woman with low moral standards. And, even then, it's really dated!  It's something my grandmother would call a woman, not even my parents.

I guess I'll add it to the crossword puzzle word file along with *etui* which means roughly the same thing.  Etui isn't used extensively outside crossword puzzles either, before it becomes your next post!